# Select top 10 sold items, oracle apex

Tags: sql, oracle, select, oracle-apex

I'm trying to find out the top sold items from my database, I have 3 tables, `se_order`, `se_items`, `se_ordered_item`. I tried the following SQL but I stuck in the group by issue, I don't see where the error is:

```
select i.name, count(max(oi.item_id*oi.quantity))
from SE_ORDERED_ITEM oi, se_items i, se_order o 
where o.order_id = oi.order_id 
  and oi.item_id = i.item_id
group by i.name, i.item_id"
```

I want to list the names of top sold items along with number of these sold items

but I get this error:

```
ORA-00937: not a single-group group function;
```

so could any one please help me in this issue

Thanks In Advance

PS, I am using apex oracle environment

Comment: what columns are there in the three tables?

Comment: SE_ORDER has:
order_id
customer_id
order_date
order_status
order_value

se_ordered_item table has:
ORDER_ID 
ITEM_ID 
QUANTITY

se_items table has:
ITEM_ID 
CATEGORY_ID 
DESCRIPTION 
VENDOR_ID 
PRICE 
ITEMS_IN_STOCK 
ITEM_IMAGE 
NAME

Answer (score 2):

Although Oracle allows nested aggregation functions, I think you want something like:

```
select i.name, sum(oi.quantity)
from SE_ORDERED_ITEM oi JOIN
     se_items i
     on oi.item_id = i.item_id JOIN
     se_order o 
     on o.order_id = oi.order_id 
group by i.name
order by sum(oi.quantity) desc;
```

Notice:

- The change to the `select` to use `sum()`.
- The use of explicit `join` in the `from`.
- The removal of `oi.item_id` from the `group by`.
- The `order by` clause.

Comment: Thanks Gordon Linoff
I tried this sql but it retrieves only the first top sold item, what i need is the top 10 sold items
thanks again

Comment: @SkyBird . . . This should actually return *all* the items ordered by the amount sold.  You can choose as many as you like.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try rownum

```
select i.name, sum(oi.quantity)
from SE_ORDERED_ITEM oi, se_items i, se_order o 
where o.order_id = oi.order_id 
  and oi.item_id = i.item_id
  and rownum <= 10
group by i.name
order by sum(oi.quantity) desc;
```

Or if you're using APEX, just use a Dinamyc PL/SQL Region:

```
DECLARE
  CURSOR items is
    select i.name, sum(oi.quantity)
    from SE_ORDERED_ITEM oi, se_items i, se_order o 
    where o.order_id = oi.order_id 
      and oi.item_id = i.item_id
    group by i.name
    order by sum(oi.quantity) desc; 
  counter NUMBER;
BEGIN
  counter := 0;

  for i in items loop
    counter := counter + 1;
    htp.p(i.name);    
  exit when counter = 10; 
  end loop;
END;
```